# Explanation of wait_event_timeout again

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization

I'm looking at the `wait_event_timeout` macro (in wait.h) and cannot understand whether it always checks for the condition before return.

Does it guarantee that, if the timeout has expired **and** the condition is true, it never returns zero?

The macro is quite convoluted to understand. Maybe I need to write a demo to proof this.... can anyone offer a simple but convincing example?

-- dd

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly. Do you mean condition becomes true at the same moment as timeout? Other two scenarios - before and after - are obvious from comments (http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/include/linux/wait.h#L371). Finally does it really matter? One can always check the condition after returning from wait_event_timeout which is what a lot of code that uses it does.

Comment: This is exactly my case. I have a project where they re-check the condition after calling wait_event_timeout. I proposed to remove what I think is redundant code,  they objected but could not explain why. Are there any corner cases or, heaven forbid, known compiler bugs that justify re-checking for the condition? Or it's just a psychology thing like er, a superstition?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer seems to be this:
The crucial change in behavior of `wait_event_timeout` occurred around kernel version 3.10.

Before this change, `wait_event_timeout` will return 0 if the event was never signaled, and it is necessary to re-check the condition manually, in case it became true somehow else (by an interrupt, another thread and so on).

After this version, `wait_event_timeout` will return 1 if the event has been never signaled, but the specified condition became true nevertheless. The API itself does the condition check after the timeout expires.

Documentation on this API in wait.h describes the new behavior explicitly since version 3.18.

Thanks for ya all who intended to help :)
-- dd